# What is the syntax for copying in makefile

Tags: makefile, copy

Code:
 copy $? $@

Can anyone tell me the meaning of " copy $? $@ "statement in makefile? What is the value $? and $@ here?

Comment: Could you provide the rule around which the copy statement appears? On surface, it seems to say, "Copy out-of-date prerequisites to target".